# Is there a way to toggle an output from a top level file with a single input?

Tags: vhdl

I am designing a system that has two separate counters performing simultaneously that both output a 4-bit binary signal to a set of 4 LEDs. One counter's output is always being displayed by the LEDs while the other counter is still counting (just without displaying an output to the LEDs). The toggle is to be activated by a single button press that will switch the output showing on the LEDs from one counter to the other.

I do not know where to even begin including this function in my design. I am not sure if I could include the logic into my top level file and toggle which signal is sent to the LEDs (I am not even sure if this is possible) or if I could include the logic necessary into the counter files. My wrapper file for the program is located below, showing the instantiation of the top level component. The outputs of the counters are tied to the same set of LEDs, one counter has the output of oQ1 and the other oQ2.

```
component top_level is
    Port ( cnt_tog  :in STD_LOGIC;
           iReset   : in STD_LOGIC;
           iUp      : in STD_LOGIC;
           iClk     : in STD_LOGIC;
           iCnt_en  : in STD_LOGIC;
--           oQ1       : out STD_LOGIC_vector(3 downto 0)
           oQ2       : out STD_LOGIC_vector(3 downto 0)
           );
end component;

BEGIN

-- INSTANTIATION OF THE TOP LEVEL COMPONENT

Inst_top_level: top_level 

      port map(
            cnt_tog     => BTN(3),
            iReset      => BTN(0), 
            iClk        => clk, 
            iCnt_en     => BTN(2),
            iUp         => BTN(1),
--          oQ1         => LD(3 downto 0)
            oQ2         => LD(3 downto 0)
        );


END structural;
```

Comment: I would not put logic into the counters. They don't need to know what will happen with their output signals. To keep the top level "clean", you could write and instantiate a **multiplexer** which switches between both counter values. Actually this is just one `if` clause so it might seem to be over-engineered. But keep the grade of abstraction in each of your levels. Now show us some effort on your side, and we will be happy to help you with specific questions if you encounter some. If you find a solution, PLEASE write an answer and don't forget to mark it.

Comment: You are not providing us with enough information. It just seems you want some switching logic, i.e. multiplexers. They are often implemented on higher levels of the design to switch functionalities. Just remember to synchronize everything up, i.e. every logic -also switches- introduce delay. Delay can lead to timing issues. So: Add registers.